# Local Wordpress site renders css differently from local Web Server

Tags: css, wordpress, wampserver, html-webpack-plugin

I'm going mad trying to solve this problem.
So basically I've written a static HTML-CSS page in order to implement it in a Wordpress custom theme.

I've got three social buttons inside the footer, in the static theme they work fine (I'm using webpack with HtmlWebpackPlugin for local frontend development). They're three links inside list elements:

```
<ul class="li-h li-h-centered">
  <li class="s-hover-facebook">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-hover-instagram">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-hover-twitter">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS that drives the whole thing is (SCSS actually, but you get the idea)

```
&__social {
padding: .5em 2em;
&>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
}
&>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 .2em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: #333;
}
font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

The result in the static website is:

[image]

The result in the Wordpress websate is this:

[image]

I really don't know what is going on here, any suggestions?

Comment: You should look in the element inspector of your browser if there are any styles that are being overridden by any stylesheets of your theme / plugins.

Comment: So, where is the __social class in your html? Did u play around with the line-height font-size?

Comment: It looks to me it has something to do with the `line-height` attribute.

Comment: The element inspector doesn't show any overridden style, the only difference is a margin-bottom on the body element. The __social class is in the parent div before the ul element. By moving the line-height in the wordpress inspector nothing happens, moving the line-height in the static inspector moves the icons.